# How to update the score column in one table with the average from columns in other three tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables that have an score column (10 points max as score)

This structure is similar to the one I have in my real database:

```
 - master_entity(id, name, **score**, other-columns...)
 - scores_table1(id, score_giver1_id, master_entity_id, **score**)
 - scores_table2(id, score_giver2_id, master_entity_id, **score**)
 - scores_table3(id, score_giver3_id, master_entity_id, **score**)
```

I would like to execute a simple **SQL script** (for MySQL database) daily with a cron job. This script must update the **master_entity.score** column with the average of the averages of the score column in other three tables.

But the average from *score column* in *scores_table1* represent just **1/6** of the average *score column* value in *master_entity*.

Also, the average from *score column* in *scores_table2 must* represent just **2/6** of the average *score column* value in *master_entity* and finally the average from *score column* in *scores_table3 must* represent just **3/6** of the average *score column* value in *master_entity*

What would be the recommended SQL to update the **master_entity.score** column using the proportional averages of scores in the other 3 tables?

Comment: Write your formula down and you'll get half of the query. Put the joins and the conditions around it to get the other half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried, but based on your question, your sql query should looks like this:

```
update master_entity m
join(
select master_entity_id,avg(score) as score 
from score_table1
group by master_entity_id
) as s1 on s1.master_entity_id = m.id
join(
select master_entity_id,avg(score) as score 
from score_table2
group by master_entity_id
) as s2 on s2.master_entity_id = m.id
join(
select master_entity_id,avg(score) as score 
from score_table3
group by master_entity_id
) as s3 on s3.master_entity_id = m.id
set m.score = (1/6)*s1.score + (2/6)*s2.score + (3/6)*s3.score
```

which master_entity.score = `(1 /6)*avg(tbl1.score) + (2 /6)*avg(tbl2.score) + (3 /6)*avg(tbl3.score)`

Comment: I changed the names of the tables to the corresponding ones and I got the results I wanted, so I think this will be OK for my script